# What is unimplemented error in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to fit a deep learning model for segmentation task (tensorflow), but i am continuously facing this error.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: Please copy your error into the question and not as an image. Also, if you can, provide a [mre] of the code

Comment: Copy the whole traceback, the current one is complete, and only as text.